# Viewer for pdflatex/beamer presentation with reload and without blurry transitions

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, latex

When using pdflatex to create a beamer presentation and then viewing it in Preview.app (single page or fullscreen mode), page transitions are blurry: when going to the next slide, a blurry/low-resolution version shows for about one second before it becomes sharp. This appears to be the case for all PDFKit-based viewers, e.g. also Skim.

Acrobat Reader does not suffer from this problem. On the other hand, it doesn't support reloading the underlying document when it has changed. So one has to close and reopen the file every time a change is made to the latex document, which is painful.

Is there a viewer for pdflatex/beamer presentations that doesn't do blurry transitions, but supports reloading?